# Merge [lumix] into [panasonic-lumix] (or vice-versa)

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

The [[lumix](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lumix)] tag should probably be merged into [[panasonic-lumix](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/panasonic-lumix)], or potentially the other way round.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went ahead and merged the [lumix] tag into [panasonic-lumix]

Comment: Thanks - is it worth having a synonym as well?